# Java Exceptions constructor & methods

Tags: java, exception, methods, constructor

I am trying to throw exceptions in the class I wrote. I also use try/catch block in main class. I want to display a message for specific exception (either legA or legB). But it is giving me only a message of the common error, not the information what leg value is invalid. What's wrong? 
this is the assignment details:

- Constructor. Accepts legs of the right triangle as arguments. Constructor throws Illegal Argument Exception when one or both legs are set to 0 or negative number(s)
- setLegA(), setLegB() - mutator methods. Both methods throw Illegal Argument Exception when leg is set to 0 or negative number.
- Have try/catch blocks that handle Illegal Argument Exception. Make sure you write the call that invokes Illegal Argument Exception in main(). In addition, make sure to call class constructors and mutator methods with bad arguments to showcase exception throwing/catching in action.

.

```
package righttriangle;
/**
 *
 * @author Liliya Sherstobitova
 */
public class RightTriangle {

   private double legA; // hold  legA length value
   private double legB; // hold  legB length value

   public RightTriangle()
   {
       legA = 0; // set start value
       legB = 0; // set start value
    }

   /**
    * constructor
    * @param a is legA length
    * @param b is legB length
    */
   public RightTriangle(double a, double b)
   {
       legA = a;
       legB = b;

       if (a<=0 || b<=0)
       {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Leg length cannot be negative");
       }
   }

   /**
    * method setLegA stores value in legA field
    * @param a is legA length
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
    */
   public void setLegA(double a) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
       if (a<=0.0) 
       {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Leg length "+a+"cannot be negative");
       }
       this.legA = a;

   }
 /**
    * method getLegA  returns a RightTriangle object's length.
    * @return the value in the legA field
    */
   public double getLegA()
   {
       return legA;
   }
}

***
piece of code from main
  try
        {
        // Test2        
        box = new RightTriangle(-5.0, 1.5);     
        System.out.println("Test 2");
        System.out.println("Right tringle legA = " + box.getLegA());
        System.out.println("Right tringle legB = " + box.getLegB());
        System.out.println("Right tringle Hypotenuse = " + box.getHypotenuse());
        System.out.println("Right tringle Area = " + box.GetArea());
        System.out.println("Right tringle Perimeter = " + box.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Either create specialized Exceptions or change the String to something like `throw new IllegalArgumentException ("[LegA] Leg length "+a+"cannot be negative");`

Comment: I don't see the `getHypotenuse` method defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code

```
   if (a<=0 || b<=0)
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Leg length cannot be negative");
   }
```

to

```
  if (a<=0)
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Leg A length cannot be negative");
   }
  if (b<=0)
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Leg B length cannot be negative");
   }
```